# Style Scrollbar using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I have a vertical scrollbar on a site and its the default IE look which is ugly, does anyone know how to use jQuery to restyle it?

Many thanks
Dil

Comment: I haven't as I dont know how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot style the scrollbar. You will have to use a plugin, like [tinyscollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

[Scroller](http://www.benplum.com/formstone/scroller/) is a great way to accomplish this. However, it only works in IE8+.

You can use it to make the scrollbar a specific width, as well as add a css class, like so:

```
$(".scrollbar").scroller({
customClass: "advanced",
trackMargin: 15,
handleSize: 40
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) . It's a cross browser styleable scrollbars with jQuery and CSS. See this [demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html).